# return result from controller to route node js

Tags: node.js

I wanted to get the result from controller to route then I will render is to view using NodeJS.

```
var request = require('request');
var crypto = require('crypto');

username = "hello@.com.ph";
password = 123124123;

auth = "Basic " + Buffer.from(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

exports.textname = function(req, res, next) {
  request.post({
    url : 'https://urlsample/api/getlist',
    headers : {
        "Authorization" : auth
    }
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    return res.json(body);
  });
};
```

Comment: What's exactly the problem you're facing? The code above seems valid.

Comment: hi sir, i hope you still interested to help me. that code stil doesnt work. its a controller sir and return res.json(body); doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code above, the anonymous function you pass on to `request.post` as the second parameter is a callback, and as such what you return from it is discarded. To return the body of the response, you should call `next()` after `res.json(body)`:

```js
// code from above...

exports.textname = function(req, res, next) {
  request.post({
    url : 'https://urlsample/api/getlist',
    headers : {
        "Authorization" : auth
    }
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    res.json(body);
    next();
  });
};
```